# Does Halacha require everyone to have a particular, specific Rabbi?

Tags: rabbis

Is every person required to have one particular rabbi to consult? Why or why not? What are the sources?

If one does have a rabbi, are those rabbi’s positions and rulings binding? Can one consult another rabbi? Can one consult different rabbis on different issues?

Sources and citations in the Torah sh bechtav, Torah sh bealpeh, or commentators appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: עשה לך רב (Avot)

Comment: What's the alternative? Make up whatever you want the rules to be?

Comment: Possible viable alternatives that do not involve making up rules: rely on a family member’s interpretation, rely on family tradition, read the sources

Comment: Does the Rabbi require a rabbi as well? I have a friend who once asked R' Yaakov Weinberg if he had a rebbi. Basically the answer was that originally Rav Hutner was his rebbi at Chaim Berlin, after he died he accepted Rav Freifeld as his rebbi, and after he died he didn't have one, but "sometimes I like to talk things over with Rav Feivel Cohen". Maybe their memories be for a blessing.

Comment: In the sefer רגל ישרה it says there are three or four people who have no Rabbi: Avraham, Hizkiyahu, and Mashiach. It says later that also Iyov had none.

Comment: @qwerty1234 Either you are qualified to render a decision (as most of us are when deciding what blessing to say on a new flavor cake) or you ask someone you trust to render a decision. There is no other option. "Rabbi" Is just someone who many trust to render many decisions.

Comment: @DoubleAA is there a source to cite? How do you decide if you are qualified?

Comment: @Loani As I read that, it advises to ask a rabbi in some cases as opposed to on this forum. That is different from affiliating yourself with a particular rabbi permanently which was the crux of this question.

Comment: @qwerty1234 Source for what? There is no other theoretical option. Asking different rabbis different things is bound to get you self-contradicting yourself soon enough if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 3):

According to Yehoshua ben Perachia, it’s at the very least a good idea to have a rabbi to consult:

> Yehoshua ben Perachia would say: “Get yourself a rabbi, acquire for yourself a companion, and give every person the benefit of the doubt.” (Pirkei Avot 1:6)

Comment: Does this imply you are always required to follow that rabbi’s instruction?  If so, are there sources or interpretations to back that up?

Comment: Does Pirkei Avot count as Halacha?

Comment: The [translations Sfaria brings for that passage](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?lang=bi&with=Translations&lang2=en) seem to prefer 'a teacher', 'a mentor', or 'a master', over 'a rabbi'.

Comment: @TamirEvan The Hebrew says עשה לך רב. *Rav* literally means “great one”, but it’s the Hebrew term for rabbi.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, a person needs a rabbi who knows their personal situation in order to render a psak in certain big life questions. And a good rabbi does more than just give rulings, he also gives personal guidance in life. (For this you need to find a rabbi who is not only competent, but also "gets" you.)

Generally you will follow this rabbi's rulings. But one also can ask other rabbis, esp. about day-to-day stuff that comes up. Rabbis tend to be busy, and you might not be able to get your rabbi on the phone immediately. When a ruling becomes binding is its own subject. Generally once you ask a Rabbi and get a ruling that is binding. You can ask your primary rabbi if a ruling you got is binding or not.

Sometimes one has to consult different rabbis in areas that require expertise. A good rabbi will tell you when you need to go to someone else. And for advice, you can consult as many people as you want.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is it a requirement? Is there a halachic source for that advice?

Comment: As @ezra said, it is generally attributed to the statement עשה לך רב.